# need to display UITableView on UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios5

I displayed UITableView  in UIImageView.but i am unable to use did select row at indexpath.

can any one help me plz in solving this.

Thanks for the showing interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, UIImageView does not have interaction enabled.  This is probably why you aren't receiving touch events to the table view.  Try add:

```
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```